# fetch data from firebase and use textfield for preview and update purposes

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview, textfield

I want to use the same objects of one `ViewController` for saving into `Firebase` and for fetching saved data to preview and update if necessary.

[image: This image to show how it look likes.]

Initially I used textfield in static cells it worked pretty well, but fail to insert text in textfield in dynamic cell.
When I call print function for the textfield in console it prints out correct value, but doesn't show anything on screen of simulator. I even tried to use simple strait text string to put it into textfield, but unsuccessful.

here is related code from `TextMessageViewController`, which i use for sending data to Firebase through textfields in dynamical tablecells

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell: TextInputTableViewCell = receiverEmailTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiverEmail") as! TextInputTableViewCell!
cell.recepientEmailTF.delegate = self
cell.recepientEmailTF.tag = indexPath.row
return cell
}
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {

if MyGlobalVariables.emails.count <= 3 {
    print("tag master = \(textField.tag)")
    switch textField.tag {
    case 0:
        if MyGlobalVariables.emails.endIndex == 0 {
            MyGlobalVariables.emails.append(textField.text!)
        }
        MyGlobalVariables.emails[0] = textField.text!
    case 1:
        if MyGlobalVariables.emails.endIndex == 1 {
            MyGlobalVariables.emails.append(textField.text!)
        }
        MyGlobalVariables.emails[1] = textField.text!
    case 2:
        if MyGlobalVariables.emails.endIndex == 2 {
            MyGlobalVariables.emails.append(textField.text!)
        }
        MyGlobalVariables.emails[2] = textField.text!
    default:
        print("exceeded")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.receiverEmailTableView.reloadData()
    }
} else {
    print("exceeded emails limit, add alert")
}
}
```

Portion of code from TextPreviewViewController from where I want to get firebase data and add it to texfields. This viewcontroller is connected to preview viewcontroller in storyboard

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in

    let newMessageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TextMessage") as? TextMessageViewController

    newMessageVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(newMessageVC!, animated: true, completion: {
        let updateButton = newMessageVC?.saveOrUpdateButton
        updateButton?.titleLabel?.text = "Update"
        let messageBody = newMessageVC?.messageTV
        let dateField = newMessageVC?.tergetDateTF

        let action = MyGlobalVariables.refMessages.child(MyGlobalVariables.uidUser!)

        // CONCERN POINT: from here->           
        let cell1: TextInputTableViewCell = newMessageVC?.receiverEmailTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiverEmail") as! TextInputTableViewCell!
        cell1.recepientEmailTF.delegate = self
                    cell1.recepientEmailTF.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true

        let texfielf = cell1.recepientEmailTF

        MyGlobalVariables.emails.removeAll()

        MyGlobalVariables.emails = ["","",""]

       // cell1.recepientEmailTF.text = "Suka blyat" <- even this simple text doesnt appear

        MyGlobalVariables.emails[0].append(self.messages[indexPath.row].email1!)           
        texfielf?.text = MyGlobalVariables.emails[0]            
       //cell1.recepientEmailTF.text =  MyGlobalVariables.emails[0] <- this code also doesnt work           

        MyGlobalVariables.emails[1].append(self.messages[indexPath.row].email2!)           
         texfielf?.text = self.messages[indexPath.row].email2!

        MyGlobalVariables.emails[2].append(self.messages[indexPath.row].email3!)
        texfielf?.text = self.messages[indexPath.row].email3!

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            newMessageVC?.receiverEmailTableView.reloadData()
        }
       //CONCERN POINT: ->up to here


        messageBody?.text = self.messages[indexPath.row].message!
        dateField?.text = self.messages[indexPath.row].setupDate!

        if let autoID2 = self.messages[indexPath.row].autoID {
            MyGlobalVariables.messageForUpdate1.append(autoID2) }
    })

}

return [edit]
}
```

My UITableViewCell class
     public class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var recepientEmailTF: UITextField!

override public func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override public func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}}
```

I would appreciate any help or advices.

Comment: The question and code is a bit unclear. If you want to display a string in a cells textfield, you need to assign it *to* the textfield, not to a textfield tag. Tags don't display in the UI. So the correct format would be `cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello, World"`.

Comment: thx for fb. Simply to say - I want to use TextField inside of dynamic cell both for 1) sending data to Firebase (this is no problem for me) and 2) the data retrieved from Firebase to place back to the same TexFields in order to preview /edit and update. in 2) case I have no problem to do it if use Textfield in static cells, but when trying to use Textfield in dynamic cell it fails. It retrieve data from Firebase but doesn't place it in `cell1.recepientEmailTF.text`. I want some help and understand what is wrong.

Comment: actually variable `cell1.recepientEmailTF.text` contains retrieved data. I can check it by print out to console, but I can see in TextField on screen of my app simulator.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. You should not be using backend database code in UI elements. Best practice is to use MVC and keep your UI elements (view) separate from your controller or model. If something changes in the UI, change your model within your controller. i.e. if a user deletes a row, delete it from the dataSource and then update your tableView. If a node is added to Firebase, let the controller add the model to your dataSource and then update your tableView. Adding redundant and repeating code to your cells ends up adding dozens of different observers of the same nodes.

Comment: Hi Jay. Thanks a lot for your comment I really appreciate it, but what you are saying that is general explanation. I want to know and would appreciate for advice what exactly wrong in my code. Because when I use static cell with UITextField it works perfectly. But why it doesn't want to work with dynamic cell.

Comment: The code may or may not be 'wrong' but it's too much code for us to digest here on SO. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What I was getting at is you don't appear to be following standard MVC practice and may be overcomplicating what you're attempting to do. IMO you should not be calling Firebase functions within tableView cells. If you read the question, it's unclear why you're not passing the firebase node key from one view to another to populate the view.

Comment: As a note, the question is kind of unclear in general so it's hard to understand the specifics of what you're doing. Remember - the scope of the project only exists in your head - we don't know that and while showing a graphic is great - it doesn't tell us what the specific issue is. To me it looks like a standard Master->Detail iOS project where the user taps on an item in the Master view and then it segues to a Detail view with... details, which can then be edited. If that's the case, either pass the documentId in the segue or pass the object in the segue and save when done.